# iis port 80 blocked to server on subnet

Tags: iis

I have an issue where port 80 is being blocked by something. My setup is as

```
- Server 1 win2008 (44.246) Server 2 win2008 R2 (40.219)
- Server 1 is running iis 7
- When I try to access http://server1:80 from server2 the connection times out
- The firewalls are off for both servers 1 and 2
- On server 1 running "netstat -ano | find ":80"" i can see server 2 trying to connect but it just stays on SYN_RECEIVED. Wireshark also shows the connection coming in.
- running "nmap -sT -p 80 --traceroute 192.168.44.246" shows "80/tcp filtered http"
- when i create another website on port 1234 or 9898 everything works correctly.
- port 80 on server 1 is accessible via the internet and works
- port 80 on another server that's on the 44 range works correctly i.e (http://server3:80 (44.231))
```

There are 3 ports that I'm aware of that are having the same connection issues. The ports are 1111,5555 and 80

what else can i use to see what is blocking these ports?

Thanks